# Finding index of element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array `teams[size]`.

```
Team* relatedTeam
```

I know that the `relatedTeam` above is member of a `teams`. So, this is pointer. How can i find its index from this information?

I am in transition from java to c++.

I am looking for a method like:

```
int pos = teams.indexOf(relatedTeam);
```

Sorry, I might not explained it well because of my poor Enghlish.

```
Team* relatedTeam = findTeam("fenerbahce");
```

and findTeam method

```
Team* SocReg::findTeam(string teamName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (stricmp(teams[i].getName, teamName.c_str) == 0)
            return &teams[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I know that team is returned without NULL from this method. So I just need its index

Comment: `relatedTeam - &teams[0]` will give you the index.  It'd be better design to just return the index in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got that

```
int index = relatedTeam - teams;
```

Comment: You could consider using std::find_if` instead of rolling out your own loop.

Comment: is it case insensitive.

Comment: I never even mentioned vector but whatever.